# how to ssh to the machine behind the firewall?

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, tunneling

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [SSH to a computer that will then SSH to another computer](https://serverfault.com/questions/91116/ssh-to-a-computer-that-will-then-ssh-to-another-computer)
>   [how to ssh to the machine behind the firewall?](https://serverfault.com/questions/305735/how-to-ssh-to-the-machine-behind-the-firewall)

I have 3 Linux machines A, B and C.

I can ssh from A to B; B to C but not from A to C directly because C is behind a firewall.

Is there a way that I can be able to ssh from A to C directly? I heard about tunneling but I don't know how. I have only root permission in A, but not B and C.

Comment: `ssh -L A:portA:C:portC user@B`

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an SSH tunnel From A to B, and use `ProxyCommand` on that connection to setup a tunnel that then allows you to SSH "directly" from A to C.  There is an example in the `ssh_config` man page (look for `ProxyCommand`) that covers exactly this use case.