# SSH directly "through" another server

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure a shortcut for an SSH connection through a SSH tunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/48808/how-to-configure-a-shortcut-for-an-ssh-connection-through-a-ssh-tunnel)

Multiple networks I can connect to have the following set up. There is a single node that can be accessed with ssh from the internet, and from there you can ssh to the inside network.

Is there a way, that on my ubuntu box (no sudo rights), I somehow can configure that the command `ssh internal.host` is first setting up an connection to external.host and from there to `internal.host`? In the ideal situation it would be something very transparent, so that I even would be able to do `scp myfile internal.host:`

All authentication is done with certificates.

Btw. I am aware of ssh tunnels. I'm only searching something more transparent, I don't want to have to always manually open an ssh tunnel to reach a host.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=proxycommand

Answer (score 1):

edit your .ssh/config file and add:

```
Host internal.host
   User abc
   ForwardX11 yes
   ProxyCommand ssh -qxT external.host netcat internal-ip-of.internal.host 22
```